Should a single update query create multiple exclusive locks on the same table in postgres (CNPG)?
My system is running instances of postgres managed using CloudNativePG; there's a primary and a couple of replicas.
When I run a query like this update <table> set <boolean-column> = NOT <boolean-column>, it's taking a while (> 19 hours) to update about ~100 million rows. I should also mention that there exists a view in the database on this table (mentioning this because it may be relevant to REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mentioned later in this post). Upon inspection, this is what I got:
SELECT 
  l.pid, application_name app, state, query,
  age(clock_timestamp(), state_change) AS change,
  age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) AS age,
  wait_event, mode, granted 
FROM pg_stat_activity p INNER JOIN pg_locks l on p.pid = l.pid 
WHERE query NOT LIKE '% FROM pg_stat_activity %' 
ORDER BY granted, age;




pid
app
state
query
change
age
wait_event
mode
granted




874173
psql
active
update t set b = NOT b;
19:39:06.762432
19:39:06.76241
DataFileRead
RowExclusiveLock
t


874173
psql
active
update t set b = NOT b;
19:39:06.762445
19:39:06.762419
DataFileRead
ExclusiveLock
t


874173
psql
active
update t set b = NOT b;
19:39:06.762448
19:39:06.762424
DataFileRead
ExclusiveLock
t


874173
psql
active
update t set b = NOT b;
19:39:06.762451
19:39:06.762427
DataFileRead
RowExclusiveLock
t




Does it make sense for the same query to have multiple ExclusiveLock locks on the same table? They are not 2 separate queries issued by different connections since the pid is the same; it's running in the same process.
And why does it also have RowExclusiveLock locks and again, 2 of them?
I understand from the documentation on ExclusiveLock locks that this lock is only acquired by REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY.
Is the instance internally running concurrent operations to update the table even though I did not explicitly ask for this to happen in my query?


I removed the general ISO/ANSI  tag since this is a very product specific question.

Check the wait_event: DataFileRead . Your system is waiting for IO

@FrankHeikens Do you think it's getting constrained due to low I/O bandwidth? At the time of testing this out, it was probably the only large query running on the instance, so I guess it's getting constrained by I/O / memory due to the large changes of the query?

As you can see, your single update uses multiple processes to execute it. However, your system can't handle this, and the different processes started to fight over IO resources. To improve performance, you have to optimize the configuration.

One more person confused by a bad query on pg_locks...


Does it make sense for the same query to have multiple ExclusiveLock locks on the same table? They are not 2 separate queries issued by different connections since the pid is the same; it's running in the same process.

Those ExclusiveLock locks aren't on a table, at all. Include  pg_locks.relation and you'll see they don't concern any specific object  (it shows null). The pg_locks.locktype will tell you they both just identify that transaction, and that it began to alter the database state:
demo at db<>fiddle
create table t(b) as select true from generate_series(1,5e4);
create index on t(b);

create extension if not exists dblink;--spawning a parallel session
select dblink_connect('_','');
select dblink_send_query('_','begin;update t set b=not b;select pg_sleep(9)');

SELECT pid
     , l.locktype
     , l.relation::regclass
     , left(p.query,12) as query
     , p.state
     , p.wait_event
     , l.mode
     , l.granted 
FROM pg_stat_activity AS p 
JOIN pg_locks AS l 
USING(pid)
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid(); --ignore my own query in pg_stat_activity




pid
locktype
relation
query
state
wait_event
mode
granted




787
relation
t_b_idx
begin; updat
active
null
RowExclusiveLock
t


787
relation
t
begin; updat
active
null
RowExclusiveLock
t


787
virtualxid
null
begin; updat
active
null
ExclusiveLock
t


787
transactionid
null
begin; updat
active
null
ExclusiveLock
t




And why does it also have RowExclusiveLock locks and again, 2 of them?

One RowExclusiveLock is for the table you're updating and I'm guessing the other concerns an index on it, which the update also has to process. The pg_locks.relation::regclass will tell you that.

I understand from the documentation on ExclusiveLock locks that this lock is only acquired by REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY.

It's an example, not the only situation it appears in. You can just open a transaction with a begin; and do nothing else, and you'll get the ExclusiveLock with locktype='virtualxid' just for that. As soon as you start writing, you'll get another one with locktype='transactionid' because that's the earliest point MVCC needs to start worrying about your actions.

Is the instance internally running concurrent operations to update the table even though I did not explicitly ask for this to happen in my query?

In general, it is. You have some level of control over that through asynchronous behaviour settings.
Thing is, you're seeing a single pid there. If you did get multiple parallel workers running the query, you'd see multiple instances of the same one query under different pids deployed for the task in pg_stat_activity,
all of which would share a leader_pid.

@Zagarek That makes a lot more sense. I didn't ask this in the question, and I guess I'll add it in there too, but can you think of any reasons that it may be taking so long for the query to finish? It is being run on an AWS t3.xlarge (4 vCPU, 16 GiB mem).

It would make sense to open a separate question to take a look at performance - this thread is already a 4 in 1. Be sure to add as much detail about the table as possible, the DDL for it and its indexes, the size, the traffic profile, vacuuming strategy, tablespace config, storage settings, etc. An explain(analyze,settings,buffers,verbose) is always welcome even for a simple update.
